# Github actions error on macos-latest-xlarge os: the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: ssl, pip, github-actions, apple-m1

I am trying to run github actions with the `macos-latest-xlarge` os. Below is the relevant part of my yml file:

```
        strategy:
            matrix:
                os: [ubuntu-latest, ubuntu-20.04, windows-latest, macos-latest, macos-latest-xlarge]
                python: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
        runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
        steps:
            - name: Checkout Repo
              uses: actions/checkout@v3

            - name: Setup Python
              uses: actions/setup-python@v4
              with:
                  python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
                  architecture: x64
```

I'm getting this error in the `actions/setup-python@v4` step.

```
Error: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Error: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
...
```

I've tried running `brew install openssl` with no luck. Any idea what could be causing this?

Note: I also had to add these lines before the python setup to get around an error with gettext:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
arch -x86_64 brew update
arch -x86_64 brew reinstall gettext
```

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/710